# Go can't access exported data in other files

Tags: go, struct

My project exports these values in different files:

```
//messages.go    
package types

    //BeaconMsg with data from google glass and the connected beacons
    type BeaconMsg struct {
        instanceID  int
        namespaceID int
        distance    int
    }

//beacondata.go
package types

import (
    "time"
)

//Beacondata with data from glasses containing beacon information
type Beacondata struct {
    instanceID   int
    namespaceID  int
    distance     int
    RegisterTime time.Time
}
```

In another file I import the types like this:

```
import (
    "glassbackend/types"
)
```

Code that throws the error:

```
req := new(types.BeaconMsg)
        if err := structFromRequest(req, r); err != nil {
            log.Errorf(context, "error extracting data from request %v", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        if req.namespaceID == "" || req.instanceID == "" {blab blabl}
```

but then this code throws me the error "req.namespaceID undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method namespaceID)(build)

Note that the code `req := new(types.BeaconMsg)` does not cast any error, only the last row of my code.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is happening? Am I doing something wrong with the exports? I don't think there is much else to do either right or wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only exported the type `BeaconMsg` (the type name), but the fields are unexported.

If you want to access the fields too from other packages, you have to export them by starting their names with a capital letter:

```
type BeaconMsg struct {
    InstanceID  int
    NamespaceID int
    Distance    int
}
```

Comment: God damn, thanks mate! :) will mark as answered when I can